# Slicing using np.array but getting IndexError

Tags: numpy, sudoku, numpy-slicing

I've been getting `IndexError: too many indices for array` at the first line of the squares.append and the other posts on IndexError just seemed a little too confusing, so it would be great if there can be a simple explanation on why I'm getting this!

```
def check_squares(grid):

squares=[]
count_dic={}
count_dic[0]=0

for num in range(1,10):
    count_dic[num]=0


squares.append(list(((np.array(grid)[:3,:3]).reshape(-1))))
squares.append(list(((np.array(grid)[:3,3:6]).reshape(-1))))
squares.append(list(((np.array(grid)[:3,6:9]).reshape(-1))))

squares.append(list(((np.array(grid)[3:6,:3]).reshape(-1))))
squares.append(list(((np.array(grid)[3:6,3:6]).reshape(-1))))
squares.append(list(((np.array(grid)[3:6,6:9]).reshape(-1))))

squares.append(list(((np.array(grid)[6:9,:3]).reshape(-1))))
squares.append(list(((np.array(grid)[6:9,3:6]).reshape(-1))))
squares.append(list(((np.array(grid)[6:9,6:9]).reshape(-1))))



for lst in squares:
    for i in lst:
        count_dic[i]+=1
    count_dic[0]=0

    if (all(value <=1 for value in count_dic.values()))==True:
        for num in range(1,10):
            count_dic[num]=0
    else:
        return False

return True

ill_formed = [[5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2],
          [6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8],
          [1,9,8,3,4,2,5,6,7],
          [8,5,9,7,6,1,4,2,3],
          [4,2,6,8,5,3,7,9],  # <---
          [7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6],
          [9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4],
          [2,8,7,4,1,9,6,3,5],
          [3,4,5,2,8,6,1,7,9]]

valid = [[5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2],
     [6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8],
     [1,9,8,3,4,2,5,6,7],
     [8,5,9,7,6,1,4,2,3],
     [4,2,6,8,5,3,7,9,1],
     [7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6],
     [9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4],
     [2,8,7,4,1,9,6,3,5],
     [3,4,5,2,8,6,1,7,9]]

print(check_squares(valid))
print (check_squares(ill-formed))

Error message: in check_squares
squares.append(list(((np.array(grid)[:3,:3]).reshape(-1))))

IndexError: too many indices for array

traceback.print_stack()


File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 245, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 241, in main
    kernel.start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2698, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2808, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-9-e4a4d877ed6a>", line 1, in <module>
    traceback.print_stack()
```

Really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @ThalishSajeed sorry, I'm not too sure what a stack trace is, I just used traceback.print_stack() in my shell so hope I posted the right thing!

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the error. If you don't mind - can you tell me what you are trying to achieve with the above piece of code?

Comment: @ThalishSajeed This is part of a code that checks for whether a sudoku puzzle (can be half done) is correct! It's a 9x9 sudoku and this section is checking that each sub-grid only has the numbers 1-9 appear once each. (a 9x9 sudoku can be divided into 9 squares)

Comment: I've added a test case, hopefully that gives the same error?

Comment: @Shouldn't you also be checking if each row and column has the numbers 1-9 appearing once?

Comment: Yes I should! But I thought I should keep the question short so I only pasted the part of the code that went wrong. Sorry for the late reply btw! I seemed to only have gotten a notification today.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution - you can try improving upon it.

```
def check_squares(grid):
    grid = np.array(grid)
    for i in grid:
        unique , counts = (np.unique(i, return_counts=True))
        #print(unique, counts)
        if len(counts)<9:
            return(False)
    for i in np.split(grid,3):
        for t in (np.hsplit(i,3)):
            unique1 , counts1 = np.unique(t, return_counts=True)
            #print(unique1,counts1)
            if len(counts1)<9:
                return(False)
    return (True)
```

Learn about numpy array splits and slicing. Do not use array reshape half a dozen times to obtain your 3*3 sub-array. I have used np `split` and `np.hsplit`

Perform all your matrix operations in the numpy space.

you can use `np.unique` with return counts set as `True` to obtain how many unique numbers are present in your input and how many times this has occurred. You can use this obtain to identify if your sub-array has repeating characters.

Suggestions - currently you are not checking if your input is valid -eg: if your input has 12 in the sudoku grid , above code does not handle it.

you were also not checking if your rows and columns are valid sudoku columns. I have handled the row situation - i'll leave the job of checking if each column is a valid sudoku column upto you

Check it out. Happy learning!

Comment: I've never heard of np.hsplit, that's an interesting solution! Thanks for sharing, but I do have a model solution and was more interested in knowing why I got the error instead. Still, this was a great answer, thanks! p.s. Unfortunately, I'm a new member so my upvote 
"will be recorded but not publicly reflected" ^^;

Comment: With regards to your error - its curious because i was not able to replicate the error on my machine